# Replacing infinitesimals with full vectors in a differential relation. Is it legit?

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, notation, vector-fields

I'm reading Leonard Susskind's "Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory". On pg. 138 he generalizes a differential relation by replacing infinitesimals with full vectors like so:

[image] 
[image]

Is this allowed? My calculus is a little rusty but I don't recall ever having seen anything like this, and my intuition tells me you can't actually do this because what holds for infinitesimals exactly will become only a poor approximation when we expand it to a full vector. Maybe also analogous to how the we can find a change very close to a point using only the first derivative but as we move away and drop terms in the Taylor series it diverges very far?  Here's how I used to think about it in calculus. In the standard relation (4.16), the $dX^\nu$s "cancel" each other giving me the $d(X')^{\mu}$ when summed over the indices but in (4.19) the $A^\nu$ and the $dX^\nu$ cannot cancel. Moreover the slope $\partial (X')^{\mu}/\partial X^\nu$ varies over the entire length of the vector $A^\nu$ which could be really really long so the slope's gonna change along the length of that vector and talking about *the* slope wouldn't really make sense. Excuse my rusty calculus but I hope someone can fill in the gaps here for me.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are not defined in the space itself, but in tangent space (sometimes regarded as an infinitesimal region of the space). The $dX^\nu$'s can be regarded as a basis for the tangent space. Any vector $A^\nu$ is then seen as a linear combination of $dX^\nu$'s.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as others pointed out, the vector lives in tangent space of given points. If you think about it, the vector is collection of n-tuple of numbers that transform with certain rule under basis transformation. The components are just these numbers. There are no functions that depend on the position, so there cannot be any varying of anything along the length of the vector.

The expression $d(X')^\mu=\frac{\partial (X')^\mu}{\partial X^\nu}dX^\nu$ must be interpreted pointwise. The differential $d(X')^\mu$ must be computed at certain point, and these 4 numbers then give you 4-vector at that point. Similarly, you are interested only in slope at the given point. Of course, for every point you get some numbers - some components which you can use to construct vector at every point, where the coordinates are defined. Having vector at any point, you arrive at vector field, which is exactly the object that defines (smoothly) one vector for every point in spacetime.

Now, in the exercise, Susskind shows that transformation induced on differential by calculus actually coincides in the case of lorentz transformation with transformation of a 4-vector. So in the case of lorentz transformations, you may as well use jacobian matrix, there is no difference - the jacobian matrix and lorentz transformation matrix have the same effect. But because jacobian matrix can be used for any kind of coordinate transformations, he makes generalization that this is how vectors are transformed.

In the case of differential, the transformation rule is given by the calculus. In the case of 4-vector, the transformation is given by the definition. Simply put, when something transforms as differentials do, it is a 4-vector, if it does not transform in that way it is not a 4-vector.

He does not prove it though (at least not in the vicinity of mentioned page), nor does he declares it as definition of 4-vector. For that, he would need to go deeper into differential geometry and talk how coordinates induce basis at tangent vector space. He just tried to show, that the rule is sensible and makes correct results in the case of Lorentz transforms.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't really get your explanation but I think I have an idea where to look. This would be under the topic of differential geometry? So it cannot be explained by just undergrad calculus right?

Comment: @user25849 Perhaps it can, I do not really know. Differential geometry at this level is quite easy though and all it does is translate ideas of linear algebra and undergrad calculus  on the manifold. This translation is moreover very intuitive and straightforward, if you have good textbook/course every step might seem almost obvious, perhaps even trivial.

Comment: Just as a point of comparison from something familiar, how can we show that vectors in euclidean space do not transform like this?

Comment: @user25849 they do. Try it for transformation from cartesian to spherical coordinates

Comment: Ahh .. right. It's coming back to me now. So the only thing differentiating the four-vector from a regular vector in euclidean space is the fact that they transform according to Lorentz Transformations correct? Meaning if I impose the condition of having to transform like Lorentz in regular vectors then the euclidian space automatically warps in to a tangent space?

Comment: @user25849 No really. Both vectors transform under lorentz transformations the same way. In fact, there is no difference at fundamental level between 4-vector in euclidean space, in flat (minkowski) spacetime or in any other 4dimesnional manifold (space). The difference between eclidean and minkowski space is only due to different metric and the difference is only in quantities induced by it. So for example scalar product of two vectors (and thus the length of the vector) is induced by the metric, and this is where the result will differ.

Comment: @user25849 The lorentz transformations are distinguished by the fact, that they keep metric invariant - that is, transformed metric is the same as the original one. But from the point of view of 4-vectors itself, it is no different transformation than any other.

Comment: @user25849  this cannot be explained in the comments though. If I can recommend you something to read, try Differential Geometry and Lie groups for Physicists by Marian Fecko. All you need to read is first 2 chapters to make all this clear.

Comment: Great thank you for the recommendation. I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

In differential geometry, the tangent space $T_xM$ located at point $x\in M$ ($M$ is the name of the space (manifold) we work on) can be realized as the set of all tangents to curves that pass through $x$.

In the non-rigorous infinitesimal framework, a way to say this is to note that $\mathrm dx^\mu$ is an infinitesimal displacement, which is basically an infinitesimal tangent to a curve. If the curve's parameter is $\lambda$, then we can form $$ V^\mu=\frac{\mathrm dx^\mu}{\mathrm d\lambda} $$ by "dividing" with $\mathrm d\lambda$. Since $\lambda$ is an invariant, if $\mathrm dx^\mu$ transforms as $$ \mathrm dx^{\prime\mu}=\frac{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^\nu}\mathrm dx^\nu, $$ then it follows that we also have $$ V^{\prime\mu}=\frac{\mathrm dx^{\prime\mu}}{\mathrm d\lambda}=\frac{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\mathrm dx^\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda}=\frac{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^\nu}V^\nu. $$

Since the tangent space at a point is the set of all tangents, then we assume that all vectors are secretly of this form, thus this transformation rule is valid universally. Of course if we muddle things with physical units then not every vector can be a tangent really, as they might have inappropriate physical dimensions, but math doesn't care about units really.

Comment: Why is it that spacetime forms a tangent space?

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about vectors in the context of manifold described by coordinates $X^\mu$ or $(X')^{\mu}$, you cannot think about them as directed lines on the manifold. Instead, they are elements of the tangent space at a specific point. There's no such thing as "points" along the vector" - there's only the point at which the vactor is anchored. And this is the point at which you're supposed to calculate $\partial(X')^\mu/\partial X^\nu$, which is the matrix of a linear transformation of cthe change of the basis in this tangent space.

Comment: Is this something that would've been covered in undergrad Calculus IV? Or is it some other topic in grad physics? If so which topic is this?

Comment: @user25849 At my university (University of Warsaw, Faculty of Physics) it is taught at Calculus III for undergrads.